# How to write .jpeg into a specific cell in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, cell, qr-code

At the moment I get data from an Excel File and generate a QrCode out of it. Then I save it as a file (.jpeg). But I need to write the QrCode into a specific cell of the same Excel file.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31294015/1943849

You'll need to use ClosedXML fork https://closedxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/ajwhiteway/ClosedXMLImageSupport

Another option is to use OpenXML (low-level access to an excel file)

Comment: Okay, thanks.. I'll try to solve my problem with that :)